# What does "got it in" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> Mr.Weasley scanned the front page while Percy looked over his shoulder.
>
> "I knew it," said Mr.Weasley heavily. *"Ministry blunders . . .culprits not apprehended . . .lax security . . .Dark wizards running unchecked. . . national disgrace* . . .Who worte this? Ah. . .of course. . .Rita Skeeter."
>
> **"That woman's got it in for the Ministry of Magic!"** said Percy furiously. "Lask week she was saying we're wasting our time quibbling about cauldron thickness, when we should be stamping out vampires! As if it wasn't specifically stated in paragraph twelve of the Guidelines for the Treatment of Non-Wizard Part-Humans..."
>
> *Harry potter and the goblet of fire*

What's the meaning of the sentence marked in bold?
I don't understand the part "got it in for".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an idiom and it can be found in most dictionaries under the entry for [**to have it in for somebody**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+it+in+for+(someone)). This expression means to persistently try or desire to criticize, cause harm to, or harass someone, especially due to a grudge (I just copied that definition from the dictionary).

Examples:

> *This is the third time in a row my professor has given me an F on my paper. I think he has it in for me or something!*
>
> *John's had it in for her ever since she forced him to sell his shares in the business.*